# Terraform error: Expected an attribute value, introduced by an equals sign ("=")

Tags: terraform

I'm really new to terraform and I'm having an issue doing something very basic.
I will only put in the relevant codes to help save time

In my variables.tf file, I have the following:

```
variable "keys_location" {
  type        = string
  description = "keys are here"
}
```

I have kept the keys that are referenced in my wrkspace.vars, I have the following:

```
keys_location = {
    "./keys/testing/certificate1.cer", 
    "./keys/testing/certificate2.cer",
}
```

And in my main.tf, I have this

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "gw" {
  name                = "testing-${terraform.workspace}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  type     = "Vpn"
  vpn_type = "RouteBased"
  active_active = false
  enable_bgp    = false
  sku           = "VpnGw1"
  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "config"
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.ip.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnet.id
  }

  test_config {
        test_protocols = ["IkeV2","SSTP"]
        address_space = [var.vpn_test_address_space]
        dynamic "keys_location" {
          for_each = var.keys_location
            root_certificate {
            name = "Root-Cert"
            public_cert_data = file(var.keys_location)
          }
        }
  }
```

When I do a terraform plan, the error I get is:

```
Error: Missing attribute value

  on vars/wrkspace.vars line 5:
   4: keys_location = {
   5:     "./keys/testing/certificate1.cer",

Expected an attribute value, introduced by an equals sign ("=").
```

How can this issue be fixed?

Comment: What is the full resource?

Comment: @Marcin I have now added the full resource on the code:

Comment: The error message is inconsistent with the provided config. Please update one or both.

Comment: @MattSchuchard this has now been updated. I made some changes to the variable names and forgot to update them here. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Your variable declaration type is inconsistent with your value, and your dynamic block syntax is invalid. However, the actual root cause of the error message is that you have a `map` or `object` constructor within your value for `keys_location`, and you are attempting to specify a `list` or `set` type. Please consult the documentation for Terraform types, variables, and dynamic blocks. There may also be other issues here besides those three.

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/language/values/variables https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/types https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks

Answer (score 1):

The Terraform [for_each meta-argument](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each) operates on maps and sets, and iteration is done over either keys and values (in the case of maps) or values (in the case of sets).  In order to iterate over the values in a set, one should use `each.key`.

In your case, because you're actually iterating over the values in the `path_to_keys` variable, the `keys_location` variable is unnecessary.  You should instead reference each of the values inside the `path_to_keys` variable.

One possible solution would be changing your `main.tf` to the following:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "gw" {
  name                = "testing-${terraform.workspace}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  type     = "Vpn"
  vpn_type = "RouteBased"
  active_active = false
  enable_bgp    = false
  sku           = "VpnGw1"
  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "config"
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.ip.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnet.id
  }

  test_config {
        test_protocols = ["IkeV2","SSTP"]
        address_space = [var.vpn_test_address_space]
        dynamic "keys_location" {
          for_each = var.path_to_keys
            root_certificate {
            name = "Root-Cert"
            public_cert_data = file(each.key)
          }
        }
  }
```

your `variables.tf` to:

```
variable "path_to_keys" {
  type        = set
  description = "keys are here"
}
```

and your `wrkspace.tfvars` to:

```
path_to_keys = [
    "./keys/testing/certificate1.cer", 
    "./keys/testing/certificate2.cer",
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see two problems with what you shared, and one of them is the cause of this error.

---

The error itself is reporting that you've used braces `{ }`, which are delimiters used for writing object/map values, but the content of the braces looks like you intended to define a list instead.

If you did intend to define a list then you should use square brackets `[ ]` to indicate that:

```
keys_location = [
  "./keys/testing/certificate1.cer", 
  "./keys/testing/certificate2.cer",
]
```

If you actually did intend to declare a map then you'll need to choose a unique key for each element, which is what this error message is trying to tell you (because it's assuming you wanted to declare a map). I can't predict what would be good map keys so I've just used some placeholder ones for example here:

```
keys_location = {
  cert1 = "./keys/testing/certificate1.cer", 
  cert2 = "./keys/testing/certificate2.cer",
}
```

---

If you make a change like I suggested above then I expect you will encounter the second error, which is that you've declared your variable as `type = string` but you've assigned it a list or map value. To make *that* work you'll need to specify a more appropriate type constraint for the variable.

If you intended to provide a list (using square brackets `[ ]`) then you could declare the variable as follows:

```
variable "keys_location" {
  type = list(string)
}
```

If you intended to provide a map (using braces `{ }`) then you could declare the variable as follows:

```
variable "keys_location" {
  type = map(string)
}
```